# How come my div element with class = "body_1"has height=0, how to align the div between footer and header?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I used the below codes to create a HTML page where I kept header and footer tags in body tag. The height of header is 16% and footer is 5%. Now I inserted a div tag in body and gave a height of 79%(100-16-5%) but when I ran the code the height of the div tag is zero, why is it and how to align the div tag between header and footer.

**Code:**

```css
body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

header{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 16%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    top: 0;


} 

.logo{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#4CD4CB;
    height:100%;
    width: 10%;

}
#head_img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
} 
.hd_div{
    position:absolute;
    height:40px;
    width: 90%;
    right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#hd_div1{
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
}
#hd_div2{
    background-color: white;
    top: 33.3333%;
    text-align: center;
}
#hd_div3{
    background-color: red;
    top: 66.6666%;

}
.body_1{
    background-color:blueviolet;
    height: 79%

}


footer{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height:5%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id='hd_div1' class='hd_div'></div>
    <div id='hd_div2' class='hd_div'>Hello This a test text </div>
    <div id='hd_div3' class='hd_div'></div>
    <div class='logo'>
        <img id='head_img' src='.\search-logos.jpeg' alt='comp_logo' >
    </div>
</header>
<div class='body_1'></div>
<footer>
    <div id='foot1'></div>
</footer>
```

**Image**:

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please share hoe to align the div element between header and footer, are you getting blueviolet background in all places except on header and footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.body_1` has hight 0 because you body has height 0.
Both header and footer are positioned absolutely which ignores body in this case.

Simple solution will be to tell `body` to have a height of `100vh` (whole window height) but you will have to apply margin from top to `.body_1` so it will not be placed under `header`
Using `position: absolute` when it is not necessary is overall a bad approach to problem.

A god solution will be to set `body` to `display: grid` which has been created for this type of job.

more about [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

In this snipper I have added grid to `body` element and removed heights from `header`, `.body_1` and `footer` (their height is now set with `grid-template-rows` so there is no point to set them in those elements).

```css
body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 16% auto 5%;
    height: 100vh;
}

header{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.body_1{
    background-color:blueviolet;
}

footer{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}


 
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#4CD4CB;
    height:100%;
    width: 10%;
}

#head_img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hd_div{
    position:absolute;
    height:40px;
    width: 90%;
    right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#hd_div1{
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
}

#hd_div2{
    background-color: white;
    top: 33.3333%;
    text-align: center;
}

#hd_div3{
    background-color: red;
    top: 66.6666%;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id='hd_div1' class='hd_div'> </div>
    <div id='hd_div2' class='hd_div'>Hello This a test text </div>
    <div id='hd_div3' class='hd_div'></div>
    <div class='logo'>
        <img id='head_img' src='.\search-logos.jpeg' alt='comp_logo' >
    </div>
</header>
<div class='body_1'></div>
<footer>
    <div id='foot1'></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly your code, and the body_0 is blueviolet:

```css
body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

header{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 16%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    top: 0;


} 
 
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#4CD4CB;
    height:100%;
    width: 10%;

}
#head_img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
} 
.hd_div{
    position:absolute;
    height:40px;
    width: 90%;
    right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#hd_div1{
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
}
#hd_div2{
    background-color: white;
    top: 33.3333%;
    text-align: center;
}
#hd_div3{
    background-color: red;
    top: 66.6666%;

}
.body_1{
    background-color:blueviolet;
    height: 79%

}


footer{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height:5%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link  rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='data:image/png;base64,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' />
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id='hd_div1' class='hd_div'> </div>
        <div id='hd_div2' class = 'hd_div'>Hello This a test text </div>
        <div id='hd_div3' class = 'hd_div'></div>
        <div class ='logo'>
            <img id='head_img' src ='.\search-logos.jpeg' alt='comp_logo' >
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class='body_1'> </div>
    <footer>
        <div id='foot1'></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm using chrome and in my case the body_1 has 0 height

Comment: Chromium Edge. I think a CSS grid solution like suggested by ciekals11 would make sense then.